# Old Core Data Sync in to CloudKit "iCloud"

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I have an app that uses Core Data but now I'm adding CloudKit to my app and I'm having issues on synchronising all the old Core Data.
Does anyone have the same issue? Does anyone have any idea how to synchronise old Core Data?

```
func fetch(completion: (_ comple: Bool) -> ()) {
        guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Goal>(entityName: "Goal")
        do {
            goalPasswords = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Fetch Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to post some code to see what the issue is and improve the chances that you will get an useful answer.

Comment: I can save in Core Data and iCloud, it's just the old Core Data content is the one not synchronizing with iCloud. If I edit and save old Core Data content it will synchronize.

Comment: Are you tracking in some way, what data you have already synced via CloudKit? Depending on the amount of data you are attempting to sync, you may be running into transaction limits. You may want to look into batching your data to sync. `NSFetchRequest` has two properties to assist with this: `fetchBatchSize` and `fetchOffset`.